# MySQL Grouping Team Tasks by Total and Completed

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have 2 tables Team and Tasks. Tasks are assigned to each team, I want a SQL (MySQL) query to get the Tasks grouped by Team based on Total and Completed Task count as illustrated below. I also want to have zero values if the count is zero in any case (both total and completed counts)

**Team Table Structure**

```sql
Team_ID int,
Team_Name varchar(50)
```

**Tasks Table**

```sql
Task_ID int,
Task_Name varchar(100),
Team_ID int (fk)
Completed bit (boolean Yes/No)
```

**Expected Results table**

| Team Name | Total Tasks | Completed Tasks Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Marvels | 6 | 4 |
| Directors | 4 | 2 |
| Commanders | 2 | 0 |
| Veterans | 0 | 0 |
| Newbies | 3 | 1 |

Addding Create and Insert Code

```sql
CREATE TABLE `teams` (
  `teamId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `teamName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`teamId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `teams` (`teamName`) VALUES ('Marvels');
INSERT INTO `teams` (`teamName`) VALUES ('Directors');
INSERT INTO `teams` (`teamName`) VALUES ('Commanders');
INSERT INTO `teams` (`teamName`) VALUES ('Vetrans');
INSERT INTO `teams` (`teamName`) VALUES ('Newbies');


CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `task_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `task_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `completed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`task_id`),
  KEY `team_id` (`team_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tasks_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`) REFERENCES `teams` (`teamId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `tasks` (`task_name`, `team_id`, `completed`) VALUES ( 'Water Plants', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `tasks` (`task_name`, `team_id`, `completed`) VALUES ( 'Feed Cat', '3', '0');
INSERT INTO `tasks` (`task_name`, `team_id`, `completed`) VALUES ( 'Go Cycling', '5', '0');
INSERT INTO `tasks` (`task_name`, `team_id`, `completed`) VALUES ( 'Prepare Food', '2', '0');
INSERT INTO `tasks` (`task_name`, `team_id`, `completed`) VALUES ( 'Clean House', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO `tasks` (`task_name`, `team_id`, `completed`) VALUES ( 'Reapair Car', '1', '0');
INSERT INTO `tasks` (`task_name`, `team_id`, `completed`) VALUES ( 'Read Book', '3', '0');
INSERT INTO `tasks` (`task_name`, `team_id`, `completed`) VALUES ( 'Video Album', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `tasks` (`task_name`, `team_id`, `completed`) VALUES ( 'Audio Album', '1', '0');
INSERT INTO `tasks` (`task_name`, `team_id`, `completed`) VALUES ( 'Walk Dog', '5', '1');
INSERT INTO `tasks` (`task_name`, `team_id`, `completed`) VALUES ( 'Get Grocery', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO `tasks` (`task_name`, `team_id`, `completed`) VALUES ( 'Plumbing Work', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `tasks` (`task_name`, `team_id`, `completed`) VALUES ( 'Audtion', '2', '0');
INSERT INTO `tasks` (`task_name`, `team_id`, `completed`) VALUES ( 'Go Fishing', '5', '0');
INSERT INTO `tasks` (`task_name`, `team_id`, `completed`) VALUES ( 'Host meeting', '1', '1');
```

Comment: Provide structure as complete CREATE TABLE. Provide sample data as INSERT INTO. Check that desired output matches provided source data.

Comment: Sorry the Task Table also has a Completion_Status boolean (Yes/No) field I missed it my bad

Comment: JOIN, GROUP BY, COUNT.

Comment: update the question with the missed column & descriptions

Comment: If Completion_Status=1 matches "completed" then you may use SUM() for to obtain completed tasks amount.

Comment: What did you try to solve this?  (Because you say "I want a SQL", and stackoverflow is not a free code writing service.)

Comment: The result from the query (post in an answer... (sigh)) are exactly the same as expected result.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the result from the query (post in an answer... (sigh)) are exactly the same as expected results, see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=675c38fdf1729bcca99cf86eaaada395)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT      
        tp.teamName 'Team Name',     
        IFNULL(final.cnt, 0) 'Total Tasks',   
        IFNULL(comp, 0) 'Completed Tasks Count'   
FROM   
teams tp
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT 
    t.teamId,
        t.teamName,
        COUNT(tk.task_id) cnt,
        IFNULL(b.Comp, 0) comp
FROM
    teams t
JOIN tasks tk ON t.teamId = tk.team_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT 
    tkp.team_id, COUNT(tkp.task_id) Comp
FROM
    tasks tkp
WHERE
    tkp.Completed = '1'
GROUP BY tkp.team_id) b ON b.team_id = t.teamId
GROUP BY t.teamId) final ON tp.teamId = final.teamid;
```

Comment: Your statement should have been added to the question (using [edit]). And it should have been formatted using [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Also: why is there `from team` in your query, when you specified a table with the name `teams` ?

Comment: Please check update query, I had posted earlier query before you added table structure and data

Comment: Thanks Krishna it works!!. I accept your answer.